# how do I create an encrypted read only view of one of the pages of my website?

Tags: django, security, encryption

My users want to create a read only view of one of the pages of the website and send it to their clients. What is the best way to do this?

I thought I would encrypt the link (example, http://ap.com/ut/dec/3/st/view_st.html) and display it in another page for them to cut and paste and view. When it is viewed, the encryption should be removed. Would this work? How would I do this?

Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: Can you give much more context? What are you trying to achieve? Please state the problem (what is the case now, and what is the end goal), and not a supposed solution ("encrypting" something if I understand correctly). Also include what you tried (or thought of) so far, which then may include potential solutions. Also the link in the question doesn't work, or is that supposed to be a sample link somehow?

Comment: The users want to send the URL of one of the web pages of our application to a list of people. This could be sent via email or any other insecure channel. That is the problem definition. What is the best way to do this? I thought if I encrypt it, it would be secure.

Comment: Why is it not secure to send a link? What is the threat (attack)? Is there sensitive info in the link itself? Do you want to allow access to the page to authorised people only? Do you think somebody would change the link while in transit?

Comment: Wait so the original link and the encrypted one should both link to the same place and both work when clicked on... Then what is the point in encryption?  Don't tell us about what you think the solution is, tell us about how the system works and the attack vector you are worried about.

Comment: The sensitive information is not in the link or the page the link points at. Let us assume this is the link http://ap.com/ut/dec/3/st/view_st.html. The user will be able to navigate to http://ap.com/ut to which he should not have access.

Comment: If you want a user to have access to `example.com/questions/123/` but not `example.com/questions/` you need to restrict access in your view code. [Here's the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users).